# Proofs of BIG-O Results involving logarithm, powers, and exponential functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms, asymptotics

this is the result in the book(Discrete mathematics and its applications) I was reading.

1. $n^d\in O(b^n)$

where $b>1$ and $d$ is positive

and

2. $(\log_b(n))^c\in O(n^d)$

where b>1 and d,c are positive

but i am having trouble understanding how that's possible
for eg in the second if you have $c$ as some big number like $10^{100}$ and d as $10^{-100}$ they both are positive
and b can be 1.0000001 how can we find a $C$ and $k$ for it to be a big-Oh notation

and in the first one if we compare the function by taking log on both sides (ignoring the d here as we can always multiply with it on the other side)

we will have

$\log(n)$ and $n\cdot \log(b)$

now which one of them is bigger as $b$ can be some number like $1.00000000001$

can some one give me proof of these two results. Thanks

edit: in the first one its not $d.n$ but $n^d$

update: i found a same question from another user [identical question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2687525/how-to-prove-that-nd-is-obn-from-n-is-o2n-given-that-d0-b1)

it's answer did clear a little bit for me but still left me confused as acc to op's accepted answer $d<log_2(b)$ where, $log_2(b)>0$.

but the result from the book is

> $n^d\in O(b^n)$

> This tells us that every power of n is big-O of every exponential function of n with a base
> that is greater than one

There is no such constraint for $d$ (as the statement says for every power of n)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Aside from that, it is expected that you show effort in solving the problem yourself and that you tell us why you are interested in this question.

Comment: in the text i am reading c and d are two positive numbers but it is not mentioned that d has to be bigger than c. that's what confusing me as in the earlier results the author was assuming that d>c>1 but not in these results and i am not able to prove that these results are true for all positive value of c and d. for eg when c is a very large number and d is very small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything comes from definition, so, let's look at it:
$$O(f)=\{g: \exists C>0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n>N, g(n) \leqslant Cf(n)\}$$

1. $d\cdot n\in O(b^n)$. As $d$ is fixed with respect to $n$, then always exists $\exists C>0$ and $C>d$. If, for example, $d>0$, (be it $10^{100}$ or more)  then we can take $C=\left\lfloor d \right \rfloor +1$. And now $d\cdot n \leqslant C \cdot n  \leqslant C b^n$, for $b>1$:
   $$\frac{n}{b^n}=\frac{n}{(1+[b-1])^n}= \\ \frac{n}{1+n(b-1)+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}(b-1)^2+\cdots+(b-1)^n}< \frac{n}{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}(b-1)^2}=\frac{2}{(n-1)(b-1)^2}$$
   So, as taking some  $C>0$ we can obtain $\frac{2}{(n-1)(b-1)^2}<C$ when $n>\left\lfloor \frac{2}{C(b-1)^2}+1 \right\rfloor +1$, then we have for same $n$-s $\frac{n}{b^n}<C$. This gives $n \in O(b^n)$ for any $b>1$
2. $(\log_b(n))^c\in O(n^d)$. Here we come out from inequality $\log_b n < n^\frac{d}{c}$ where $\frac{d}{c}>0$. Most easy is reach this with [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), but is possible, also with direct analysis. Tricky is only case $\alpha = \frac{d}{c} \in (0,1)$. Write if you would like to see it and I'll elaborate.

Comment: i have commented on the first answer mind checking it out

Comment: and the first one is not d⋅n∈O(n) but n⋅d∈O(b^n) where b>1 and d is positive number

Comment: @Jordan jarvis. Thanks for correction, I fixed it as $n <b^n$, for $b>1$, so all argumentation keeps correct. As to your first comment to other, first, answer, then $d$ cannot influence on $C$ taking from big-$O$ definition. You firstly take $d, b$ constants and for them formulate $d\cdot n\in O(b^n)$, so $C$ can be chose as I brought in my answer. Write if/when something remains unclear.

Comment: so $b^n$ is a bigger function than n. how? like if we take a very small value of b that is greater than 1 like 1.0000000000001 when will this function ($b^n$) be bigger than n

Comment: sorry i made a mistake here in the first one it is not $n.d$ but $n^d$. but my earlier comment still holds true how to prove $b^n$ is bigger than n.

Comment: @Jordan jarvis. Just now I have lecture, I'll answer approximately after 2 hours.

Comment: alright i'll try figuring out.

Comment: I've updated my question by finding an identical question.

Comment: @Jordan jarvis.  Added to answer proof $n \in O(b^n)$ for $b>1$. Do you need some more explications?

Comment: thanks got it finally

Comment: Welcome. Write, if/when you'll need some more help.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $f(x)\in O(g(x))$ if
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sup\frac{|f(x)|}{g(x)}<\infty$$
For part $1$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\frac{|nd|}{b^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|d|}{\ln(b)b^n}=0$$
by l'Hopital's rule. Since $0<\infty$, we know $nd\in O(b^n)$.

For part $2$:

For the base case $c=1$ we have:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\frac{|\log_b(n)|}{n^d}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{n^d\ln(b)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{n^{d-1}\ln(b)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^d\ln(b)}=0$$

Thus $\ln(n)\in O(n^d)$.

Now suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\frac{|\log_b^{c-1}(n)|}{n^d}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln^{c-1}(n)}{n^d\ln^{c-1}(b)}=0$, i.e. $\ln^{c-1}(n)\in O(n^d)$. Then for $\ln^c(n)$ we have:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\frac{|\log_b^c(n)|}{n^d}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln^c(n)}{n^d\ln^c(b)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\ln^{c-1}(n)}n}{n^{d-1}\ln^{c-1}(b)\cdot\ln(b)d}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln^{c-1}(n)}{n^d\ln^{c-1}(b)}\cdot\frac1{\ln(b)d}=0\cdot\frac1{\ln(b)d}=0$$

And by induction $\ln^c(n)\in O(n^d)$.

For non-integer $c$, suppose there is an integer $m$ such that $m>c$. Now   $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\frac{|\log_b^c(n)|}{\log_b^m(n)}=\log_b^{c-m}(n)$. As $\log_b(n)$ approaches infinity, and $c-m<0$, $\log_b^{c-m}(n)$ approaches $0$. Thus $\log_b^c(n)\in O(\log_b^m(n))\in O(n^d)$.

Comment: the text i was reading didn't give me any knowledge about induction or using limits. it went form a simple result to these two. my only problem with these results is that c and d are any positive numbers and in earlier result the author mentioned that d>c>1 and proved a result that i understood but in these two he just mentioned that d and c are positive and that's what confused me as I am very new to big-oh notation. if there were any constraint that c has to be smaller than d. then i could prove it but with c and d just being positive it's hard to imagine how to prove them at my state.

Comment: is there any other way to prove that or should I just take a leap of faith that later in my reading i can solve them with the method you showed me. but again if i needed that knowledge to solve these results why did author bother putting them so early in the book.