# "Limit definitions" of asymptotic (Bachmann-Landau) notation

Tags: limits, notation, asymptotics, computational-complexity

[This table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) has a column for "formal definitions" and another for "limit definitions" of the family of Bachmann-Landau notations.

**What exactly are *limt* definitions and how do they relate to the *formal* definitions?**

Since the notation is used to describe the asymptotic growth of functions, I thought the formal definitions were "limit" definitions themselves.

I'm especially not sure how the limit definitions for O, Ω and Θ are equivalent to their respective formal definitions. In the book *Introduction to Algorithms*, only the limit definition of Θ is given and it appears as a theorem (see [Theorem 3.1](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=NLngYyWFl_YC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=theorem%203.1&f=false))

Comment: Is there a reason why you think they are not equivalent?

Comment: I don't doubt they are equivalent, I'm just not sure how. A [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172821/how-to-prove-that-big-o-definition-is-equivalent-to-its-limit-definition#comment4469099_2172821)  on another post seems to say that they aren't definitions, which confuses me.

Comment: For big-O, notice that Wikipedia's limit definition uses $\limsup$, while the other post uses $\lim$. As the commenter points out, with $\lim$ there is only a one-way implication instead of an equivalence. // To focus your question, I would pick one row of the table and try to prove (or disprove) whether the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you @angryavian, that clears it up. Could you please explain why **lim** only has a one-way implication instead of equivalence?

Comment: The limit definitions given [here](https://blogs.ubc.ca/cpsc3202016w1/files/2016/09/2016-09-19-little-o-and-omega-handout.pdf) and elsewhere are confusingly all in terms of **lim** instead of **lim sup** and **lim inf**.

Comment: For your first question read [Did's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172821/how-to-prove-that-big-o-definition-is-equivalent-to-its-limit-definition#comment4469099_2172821) again. If $f(n) = \begin{cases} n & \text{$n$ even} \\ 0 & \text{$n$ odd}\end{cases}$ and $g(n)=n$, then $f(n)=O(g(n))$ but $f(n)/g(n)$ doesn't have a limiit.

Comment: For your new link, note that #1 and #2 are talking about little-$o$ and little-$\omega$, for which the "limit definitions" use $\lim$ and agree with Wikipedia. Their #3 is incorrect though; $f(n)/g(n) \to c$ implies $f(n) \in \Omega(g(n))$, but the converse isn't necessarily true since the limit of $f(n)/g(n)$ might not exist.

Comment: Thanks so much @angryavian.